# What alpha value to choose for JPG when doing alpha compositing of a JPG and PNG

Tags: image, image-processing, alphablending, alpha-transparency

Alpha Compositing can be seen here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing.
Now, given a png with alpha value, and a jpg without alpha value, how to use Alpha Compositing to combine them?

Comment: JPEG doesn't support transparency so the alpha will be 1 or opaque. So, you better put JPEG underneath at the bottom of your compositing layers as nothing will show through.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That is irrelevant if the purpose is to _give_ the image alpha...

Comment: As for the question... what programming language / tool are you using? What have you tried? What is the actual _problem?_ There are many ways to handle this, but if you already _have_ said images, what kind of data do they actually contain?

Comment: Specifically, do they both contain image data, or is one purely image and the other purely alpha? And is that alpha represented as actual alpha channel, or as grayscale image?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose GIMP as tool, https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-image-combining.html might be helpful for you.

If both the JPG and the PNG input file have exactly the same size (width x height x pixel density), I suggest to

1. assume or define a certain, constant alpha value for the complete JPG picture (as a layer in GIMP)
2. renormalize the alpha value (field) of the PNG file and define it as another layer
3. add the two field values, e.g. you could add layers in GIMP.

The exact mathematics you want to use really depends on the specific application. If the alpha value (field) carries information on your scientific experiment, setting the alpha value for the complete JPG to 0 might not be ok and you would have to choose e.g. 255/2 (if your alpha channel has 256 allowed values).